# One answer and its comments were blank

Tags: bug, android-app

I got notification from one question. One guy replied to my comment. I clicked it and Stack Exchange app started loading. I clicked the notification in in-app notifications bar and it redirected me where it should: [Link from the notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names/31976060?noredirect=1#comment74022686_31976060).

But, when I scrolled up, one answer (DourHighArch's) and its comments were blank. They looked like every text on them was just set to white color. It was tall enough, so its content would fit it. (I mean, it was looking like there was some content, but written in white)

Sorry if I made something wrong in this "question", it is first time I report an error and I wasn't sure how do I do that. Also, sorry if duplicate.

Screenshots:

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

**PS:** When I re-visited the linked page, everything was correct, like if this was random issue.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: samsung
- Device Model: GT-I9305
- OS Version: 4.4.4 (I9305XXUFNJ1)

Comment: Big thanks for the one to fix those screenshots!

Comment: It looks like something interfered the connection to SE servers while loading the answer. But what is weird; as I said the answer was sized like if it had content, while an loading answer does not work like that.

Comment: @Arulkumar I used this and there was the no mime_type error.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, oh yeah. Looks like my issue...